# Try-before-you-buy

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, trial

I want to submit an app I wrote to the Windows store. All the examples I have found about implementing trial functionality in an app, seem to be dated. For example, most tell you to add the using directive 'using Microsoft.Phone.MarketPlace; which causes Visual Studio 2013 to ask if I have forgotten an assembly reference. Am I supposed to add a NuGet package or something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace;
```

Can anyone suggest a good, reliable, and current source of information?

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the `Microsoft.Phone` assembly, Microsoft.Phone.dll.

It may be available as an assembly reference on your machine, I couldn't see it on nuget.org.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.marketplace.licenseinformation(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this caused many errors in my previously functioning app. Your suggestion DID lead me to do further research into the Windows Phone 8.1 reference using the Object Browser. I believe I found my own solution right there. I removed the Microsoft.Phone reference and changed my using statement to using Windows.ApplicationModel.Store;